Start tomcat with custom startup within Eclipse IDE
For debugging purposes, I need to start the Tomcat server with a custom script; however, the Eclipse IDE plugin prevents my start script from starting the Tomcat server. Please advise me on how to I use the debug mode on Tomcat. Tomcat command as below
nuxeoctl console

here no runnable script path provided.
I appreciate your generous contribution in advance.
Thanks.

What is the problem that you've concluded should be solved by using a shell script?  As it is, debugging anything on a Tomcat server already launches Tomcat itself using the debugger.

I want to know where need to give startup script. I didn't find the place where it is specified. If have idea please guide

What problem does using a script solve? Right now this looks like an XYProblem. You are asking about your attempted solution rather than your original, actual problem. As you've pointed out, the in-IDE path for launching Tomcat doesn't let you plug in a script, and I'd again question what having one would let you do.

I need to run nuxeo platform server which run on Tomcat 9. Nuxeo server follow OSGi framework. I need to customize nuxeo web ui. And nuxeo application via nuxeoctl console. that's a reason I need to give this file instead of startup.bat

Launch support in Eclipse is launching the JVM with the options to run Tomcat. If you don't launch Nexeo when outside of Eclipse by using the unmodified catalina script that Tomcat provides, then this isn't going to work.
